# FileSystemWatcher only shows memory adress, but not the name of the changed file

Tags: c#, filesystemwatcher

I have the FileSystemWatcher, that is watching for the changes in one folder. I have created a FileSystemEventHandler(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e), where I do some random operations and also trying to get the name of the file with: `Console.WriteLine(e.Name)`

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemeventargs.name?view=netframework-4.8) it says that this property should give me the name of the file, but what I am getting is a memory code of file (as I think), for example: F8B11010

```
private void Watcher(string path) 
{ 
    fsw = new FileSystemWacther(path)
    fsw.Changed += new FileSystemEventHanlder(fsw_changed);
    fsw.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
}

private void fsw_changed(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
     Console.WriteLine(e.Name);
     *other code*
}
```

As I understand, this happens because the file which is being changed is opened at the same moment with Excel. But maybe there is still a way to get its name?

Comment: Please, share us your code

Comment: Added. I think this happens because the file that is getting changed is also opened in Excel. But I don't know is this how it should work or no

Comment: Afaik, ms office apps creates a temp file in the same folder with document. Try to restrict `NotifyFilter` for `FileSystemEventHanlder` and check

Comment: Used fsw.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastWrite; But nothing changed. Maybe there is another way to get the name of the file that is used by ms office?